# Trello to Jira migration and sync up

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, trello, trello-powerup

I have my team Board in TRELLO. I want to Migrate the same to JIRA now. I want them to be in sync at both place. ie if anyone updates any task in TRELLO, it should be updated in JIRA board as well. Is this doable?

I checked the only power up available is UNITO plugin, but its a paid tool. aAny other option other than that?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can import data from Trello to JIRA using JIRA itself. Check out https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/importing-data-from-trello-951386555.html
2. You can use this synchronization tool provided by Atlassian to make JIRA and Trello in sync. Check out https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215077/trello-sync-for-jira/version-history